# Spinner entries bindingadapter room livedata not working

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am working on room livedata databinding concept. I am setting list to spinner using custom binding adapter. But i am getting null livedata while retrieving from room firsttime.

code:

```
     @Query("select * from Student")
        LiveData<List<Student>> getAllItems();


        @BindingAdapter({"bind:entries"})
            public static void customSpinnerBinding(AppCompatSpinner appCompatSpinner,LiveData<List<Student>> listLiveData){
                if(listLiveData != null && listLiveData.getValue().size() > 0){
                    ArrayAdapter<Student> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>
                            (appCompatSpinner.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    listLiveData.getValue()); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
                            .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    appCompatSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                }
            }

        public LiveData<List<Student>> getListLiveData() {
            if(listLiveData == null){
               listLiveData = studentDB.studentDao().getAllItems();
            }
            return listLiveData;
        }

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    bind:entries="@{viewmodel.listLiveData}"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

but if i observe livedata in activity this is working

  mainViewModel.getListLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Student>>() {
           @Override
           public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Student> students) {
               if(students.size() > 0){
                   ArrayAdapter<Student> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>
                    (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                            students); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
                    .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            activityMainBinding.appbar.contentid.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
               }
           }
       });
```

Comment: share your Viewmodel code.

Comment: everything i shared, i am just setting livedata list to spinner

Comment: Have you attach the viewmodel to view in activity.

Comment: check updated code

Comment: checkout this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/53660823/7592063.

Comment: if using Room, you have to read data in background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these two things:

1. Change your `.customSpinnerBinding` to accept a `List<Student>` instead of `LiveData<List<Student>>`.

`BindingAdapter` accepts what goes inside of a `LiveData` , not the `LiveData` itself. `LiveData` is not the one that changes. Only the content of the `LiveData` notifications change.

Example BindingAdapter:

```
        @BindingAdapter({"bind:entries"})
        public static void customSpinnerBinding(AppCompatSpinner appCompatSpinner, List<Student> students) {

            ArrayAdapter<Student> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>
                    (appCompatSpinner.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                         students); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            appCompatSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        }
```

2. Do not lazy load `listLiveData`

It looks like your view will need it anyway, what is the point of lazily loading it? It will only make your code more complex and harder to debug by making your viewmodel more stateful. Just eagerly load the student list, and declare it as final to make it even better.

```
public final LiveData listLiveData = studentDB.studentDao().getAllItems();
```

If you must lazy load `listLiveData` then make sure it gets initialized. In your .xml:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                ...
                bind:entries="@{viewmodel.getListLiveData()}"
                ... />
```

Comment: actually i got the solution  bind:entries="@{viewmodel.listLiveData.getValue()}",but anyway you mentioned same thing

Comment: I am not mentioning the same thing.. Normally you should not use 'getValue' on the 'LiveData'. 'getValue' gets the value synchronously, and only one time which defeats the whole point of using a 'LiveData'.

Comment: bind:entries="@{viewmodel.getListLiveData()}"  if i provide like this it is not working and binding error coming

Comment: what i understood, in xml we can't directly provide livedata.

Comment: i am getting listLiveData.getValue() null in viewmodel  spinner binding adapter, i guess only way using livedata observers  only we can data

Comment: getting null on `listLiveData.getValue()` is very normal because `getValue()` literally gets value even when `LiveData` doesn't have any value yet. Have you tried the other approach--not lazy loading the `LiveData`? As far as I know you CAN directly provide a `LiveData` if you defined your viewmodel in <data> tag and assigned the viewModel in the binding in your Activity/Fragment.

Comment: i didn't define livedata in data tag, but still i can get list values inside spinner binding adapter because xml livedata fetching values asynchronously

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194213/discussion-between-sanlok-lee-and-skyshine).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
listLiveData = StudentDB.getAppDatabase(application).studentDao().getAllItems();
return listLiveData;
```

Comment: Check whether this studentDB.studentDao().getAllItems() is returning data or not.

Comment: I think you are not observing data. That's why. Try listLiveData.setValue(list);

Comment: yes it is returning but it is working if i do listLiveData.observe in activity

Comment: Try now this code listLiveData.setValue(studentDB.studentDao().getAllItems());

Comment: you don't need to setvalue from room we are getting listLiveData which contains list of objects

Comment: i am getting listlivedata from db, can you check my code again